# Automatically increase the Counter till it meet the required Condition In React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am working on a simple app where I want the user to enter a  two-digit number and after pressing confirm I want to make the below counter run like ex 10,11,12,13,14,15 and so on and stop when we get the value that user-inputted for ex 65 it will stop when the counter reaches to 65 the purple text box is where the counter is to be displayed.[image]

> 

**This code defines the outlet of second  text box  in  this code props.children will aquire  value that will be inputted by the user for ex 11 ,10 etc  And I also have this Number Component that  basically take care of how number will be shown inside that purple textbox(used for styling purpose) ,and In Number component I need that counter logic to  be implemented  **

```
import React from "react";
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      TextInput,
      Button,
      TouchableOpacity,
    } from "react-native";
    import Card from "./Card";
    import Color from "../constants/color";
    import color from "../constants/color";
    import Number from "./Number";
    const Counter = (props) => {


      return (
        <Card style={styles.styleCounter}>
          <Text>Number selected is </Text>
          <Number>{props.children}</Number>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>START GAME</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Card>
      );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      styleCounter: {
        marginTop: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        width: "50%",
        height: "40%",
      },
    });

export default Counter;
```

Below is the Code for Number Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import Card from "./Card";
import Color from "../constants/color";
import color from "../constants/color";

const Number = (props) => {
  let intial = 10;

  return (
    <View style={style.inputContainer}>
      <Text>{props.children}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  number: {
    color: "#c717fc",
    fontSize: 22,
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  inputContainer: {
    margin: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    width: "40%",
    height: "40%",
    borderColor: "#c717fc",
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
});

export default Number;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, post some code so we could help you.

Comment: Code is now posted

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1. make two state variables input and counter,
2. when the user inputs a number, store it in the state "input" variable
3. run a simple loop in a separate function where perform increment on temp variable,
4. when temp reaches input, set counter value to temp, as you are using state, the counter in the UI will be automatically updated.

Comment: which value  should be rendered then temp ,or counter can you please see the code that 
 I have posted

Comment: @ShashankDubey you will have to render "counter" if you want to show the last output only, otherwise if you want to show increment as well at counter place like it changes from 1,2,3,..., then remove temo and increase counter only. and render counter